# How to find the weblogic jmx attributes for a objectname

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx, objectname

I am writing simple client application to connect to weblogic and list all the libraries that a webapp is depending on.However, I am having difficulty in finding the right attributes for a objectname. For example,

If you look at the below sample code given on oracle.com to connect MBeanServer

```
public static void initConnection(String hostname, String portString,
  String username, String password) throws IOException,
  MalformedURLException {

  String protocol = "t3";
  Integer portInteger = Integer.valueOf(portString);
  int port = portInteger.intValue();
  String jndiroot = "/jndi/";
  String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit";

  JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(protocol, hostname, port,
  jndiroot + mserver);

  Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
  h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
  h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
  h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES,
     "weblogic.management.remote");
     connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
     connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();


}

public ObjectName startEditSession() throws Exception {
  // Get the object name for ConfigurationManagerMBean.
  ObjectName cfgMgr = (ObjectName) connection.getAttribute(service,
     "ConfigurationManager");



  // Instruct MBeanServerConnection to invoke
  // ConfigurationManager.startEdit(int waitTime int timeout).
  // The startEdit operation returns a handle to DomainMBean, which is
  // the root of the edit hierarchy.
  ObjectName domainConfigRoot = (ObjectName) 
     connection.invoke(cfgMgr,"startEdit", 
     new Object[] { new Integer(60000),
     new Integer(120000) }, new String[] { "java.lang.Integer",
     "java.lang.Integer" });
  if (domainConfigRoot == null) {
     // Couldn't get the lock
     throw new Exception("Somebody else is editing already");
  }
  return domainConfigRoot;




}
```

The line 
ObjectName cfgMgr = (ObjectName) connection.getAttribute(service,
         "**ConfigurationManager**");

Is referring to a JMX attribute **ConfigurationManger**. How can we find all the attributes that are under a given objectname in weblogic?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I found the solution.

You get attributes for a ObjectName by calling getBeanInfo on the ServerConnection!

Example:

`MBeanAttributeInfo[] beanInfo = (connection.getMBeanInfo(objectName)).getAttributes();`

for(MBeanAttributeInfo info:beanInfo)
   System.out.println(info.getType()+" "+info.getName());

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [WebLogic Classloader Analysis Tool (CAT)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm) can give additional insight out of the box ...